# Service account can create PubSub subscriptions but can't read from them

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I've created a service account I intend to use in our development environment, and since its credentials are checked into source control, I want to lock down its access to the bare minimum.

When spinning up new hosts, our app creates a new PubSub subscription, listens on the newly created subscription, then deletes it when finished. We chose this model over having a number of preconfigured/hardcoded subscriptions because the number of hosts scales up and down with time, we don't want host-specific config (In the form of a host-subscription map) if possible, etc. We want to have this same behavior in our local development environments ideally for debugging.

I created a specific "development" topic and granted our development service account the Pub/Sub Admin role, allowing it to attach subscriptions to that topic. I also granted the service account the project-level permission that allows it to create subscriptions. The service account can successfully create a new subscription and attach it to the topic, but when it tries to read from the new subscription, I receive a permission denied error.

I'm guessing this is because, when checking the newly created subscription, I notice that the service account that created it is not granted any permissions of any kind to that subscription. I would've expected the account that created a subscription to at least have read rights to it.

Is there a way for a service account to create subscriptions, attach them to a topic, and then read from that subscription... while not giving the service account access to any other subscriptions or topics? I'm aware I could just give the service account a "higher level" role with access to read all subscriptions, but that defeats the purpose of having a development-only account.

Answer (score -1):

After your service account creates the subscription, it can call setIamPolicy on the subscription to grant itself read access to it. This works because you gave your service account the pubsub admin role on the project, which includes the ability to call setIamPolicy on any subscription in the project.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/setIamPolicy

Comment: Because this is a development service account, I don't want it to be able to call SetIamPolicy() on *any* subscription in the project, only ones attached to the development-only topic to which I granted it permissions.

Is there any way to grant the service account permissions to read newly-created subscriptions on a non-project wide basis? If permissions are only per-project and not-per topic, then there's no way to have a test account (Without production topic/subscription access) except by creating a new project...?

Comment: Ah, apologies. I misunderstood. I'm not aware of any way to group topics or subscriptions for the purposes of IAM policies, and it looks like it's not possible to specify an IAM policy on a subscription at creation time. Not ideal, but you could create a new project just for the purposes of holding subscriptions.

Comment: Brentonium, did you find a solution to this? I have a similar situation where I want services to add themselves as subscribers to a topic. There are many of them, and they will come and go, so I don't want to have to manage their individual subscriptions manually via Cloud Console.